# How to use ajax autocomplete for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $(".auto").autocomplete("omsaiautocomplete.php",{
       width: 260,
       matchContains: true,
       //mustMatch: true,
       //minChars: 0,
       //multiple: true,
       //highlight: false,
       //multipleSeparator: ",",
       selectFirst: false   
    }); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete("omsaiautocomplete1.php",{
           width: 260,
           matchContains: true,
           //mustMatch: true,
           //minChars: 0,
           //multiple: true,
           //highlight: false,
           //multipleSeparator: ",",
          selectFirst: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

i have above code which is used for two textboxes having autocomplete applied to them.is it right? plz provide answer.

Comment: Format the code please. There's a handy guide to the right of the "Add/Edit Question" box, with a link to further instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to setup both autocompletes on the same text boxes (ones with the class 'auto'). Give each textbox a unique class/ID and then setup the autocomplete using that instead.